# How resource server should validate oauth bearer token that issued by Authorization Server?

Tags: security, authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt, openid-connect

Let's assume I have an Authorization Server (AS), which are supposed to produce `access_token`, and that I have another Resource Server (RS), which serves my protected resources.

I'm wondering how should RS validate the `access_token` that produced by AS?

My confusion is that, AS should has its secret way on signing `access_token`, which not meant to be shared nor known by anyone else, which in this case RS should not has any idea on how AS generated this `access_token`.

In this case how should RS validate the received token and ensure the token is coming from the recognized AS? Instead, shouldnt it to be AS's responsibility to validate the received token on RS? But if thats the case wouldnt it facing any performance bottleneck, since every API call to RS will need extra hop to AS to validate the token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the tokens issued by the AS is signed using a private key. The AS also publishes is public key for anyone to download. For example Google publishes its public siging key [here](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs).

Later when the RS received the access-token, it downloads the public key from the AS and verifies the signature of the token. If match its accepted. Besides validating the signature, it also checks the other claims inside the token, like the aud-claim (audience) if he token is actually intended for the RS to consume or not.

Alternatively, the RS can use a shared secret to validate the tokens. In this case the RS is a trusted (confidential client) that we know can keep secrets and its safe to share the secret with services that we trust.

Answer (score 1):

As you say Isaac, some people (including myself) prefer to externalise the token validation from APIs and ask the Authorization Server to do the work. I think this is the cleanest option since:

- It externalises security code from all of your APIs
- The token signing key or algorithm can be changed without impacting APIs

This is possible via [introspection](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662), which typically also involves caching the results (claims). This is how quite a few API gateway solutions work, but you can also code it yourself quite easily.

A couple of related resources of mine:

- [API Authorization Blog Post](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims/)
- [Introspection Code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/tree/master/api/src/host/oauth)

The technique Tore describes is also perfectly valid, and is a requirement if the Authorization Server does not support introspection.